# How to do wild card subdomains in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Ryan Bates [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/123-subdomains-revised?autoplay=true) on subdomains, he gives the following way to match subdomains

```
# config/routes.rb
match '', to: 'pro_users#show', contraints: lambda { |r| r.subdomain.present? && r.subdomain != 'www' }
```

but match without the HTTP verb was deprecated in rails 5, so this gives an exception

```
You should not use the `match` method in your router without specifying an HTTP method.
```

So how do you do this in rails 5 and above?

Comment: How many subdomains are you supporting?

Comment: No definite number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In rails 5, you have to specify which HTTP verb that you want to use. So in if you want to use that route for get and post, you would write

```
# config/routes.rb
    match '', to: 'pro_users#show', via: [:get,:post], contraints: lambda { |r| r.subdomain.present? && r.subdomain != 'www' }
```

You might also like to clean up the constraint by using a contraint class, this blog has some [suggestions](https://8thlight.com/blog/ben-voss/2013/01/12/how-to-use-rails-route-constraints.html).

So you could write the route matcher as

```
# config/routes.rb
match '', to: 'pro_users#show', via: [:get,:post], contraints: SubdomainConstraint }
```

and

```
class SubdomainConstraint
   def self.matches?(request)
     request.subdomain.present? && request.subdomain != 'www'
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @obromios, I am new to this but in future, I will remember your word